# Update asp.net gridview element from json specification

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, gridview, webforms

I have a simple aspx page "Default" with a code behind. The code behind has a set of simple methods.

What I'm looking to do is to create a method OnGridViewChange() - see the mockup below - which is called whenever the user changes a row in the gridview. The row updates a local list of Rows and then converts to object to a json string which is showed to the user.

Essentially what I'm building is a glorified json viewer in asp.net web forms which takes a json string, displays it as a table and then updates the json and table on user changes.

I think I have most of the major methods outlined below, but what I need help with is the OnUpdate method,

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    public class FoobarRow
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int NumberOfHats { get; set; }
    }

    public List<FoobarRow> FoobarRows { get; set; }= new List<FoobarRow>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Vera important json formatted string. Gets updated when gridview changes
    /// </summary>
    public string Json { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates gridview on the page from the json entered by the user on a previous page
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FoobarRows = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FoobarRow>>(GetJsonFromUserWhenPageLoads());
        UpdateGridviewFromList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Actually updates the gridview from the list of FoobarRows
    /// </summary>

    private void UpdateGridviewFromList()
    {
        ApplicationGridView.DataSource = FoobarRows;
        ApplicationGridView.DataBind();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Is called whenever user edits any row in the gridview and saves the changes. Updates the json and the local list of rows
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rows"></param>
    public void OnGridViewChange(List<FoobarRow> rows)
    {
        FoobarRows = rows;
        DisplayCurrentJsonOnPageForUser(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows));
        UpdateGridviewFromList();
    }

    public string GetJsonFromUserWhenPageLoads()
    {
        //Finish later
        return "some json the user will have entered on a previous page and will be loaded into a label or something of the like";
    }

    public void DisplayCurrentJsonOnPageForUser(string json)
    {
        //Finish later
    }
}
```

Having looked around, I found this documentation from Microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 about the aspx gridview but it seems needlessly complicated for my usecase.

Does anyone know of any datagrid plugin for webforms or other asp.net element that would allow me to tie changes to a simple event such as OnGridViewChange(). I'm new to web forms and the above mentioned article from Microsoft is the best I've managed to find but I feel like there must be a better way!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this can be achieved by using this event model found here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396